# Calculating the most similar pair of column vectors using cosine distance in a matrix

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra

I have a 943x1682 matrix in which I want to calculate the two most similar vectors in this matrix. So I want see the cosine distance of each vector in the matrix to each vector in the matrix, of course not including the vector with itself, if one cannot do that I can just ignore those.

[image: code (image)]

I made this loop to try to calculate this, so I can get a 1682x1682 matrix, with each cell corresponding to the similarity between `i` and `j`. However when I run this, it takes forever to run, and when I try to open the resulting matrix in my workspace, it says:

> Cannot display summaries of variables with more than 524288 elements.

Is there an easier way to do this or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Also note, that `tok` should be spelt `toc`

Comment: please share your code here instead of using images.

Answer (score 2):

Cross posted on MATLAB Answers. Repeating answer here:

Use a standard matrix multiply to get the dot products.  MATLAB is very fast at standard matrix multiplies.  And then normalize the result.  E.g.,

```
AA = A' * A; % the column dot products via a standard matrix multiply
Anorm = sqrt(diag(AA)); % the norms of the columns
Adist = AA ./ (Anorm .* Anorm.'); % normalize the column dot products into cosine distances
```

Then pick off the maximum value for your answer, disregarding the diagonal.  E.g.,

```
n = size(A,2); % the number of columns
Adist(1:n+1:end) = -inf; % disregard the diagonal (column compared to itself)
[~,x] = max(Adist(:)); % find the max cosine distance linear index
[col1,col2] = ind2sub(size(Adist),x); % convert linear index into the original columns
```

Then col1 and col2 are the column numbers of the most similiar columns using cosine distance as a measure.

Answer (score 1):

You can normalise the columns of the matrix first, then the cosine similarity equation simplifies to a matrix multiplication:

```
aNorm = normc(A);
cosSim = aNorm' * aNorm;
```

Generally, matrix multiplication is more performant than looping. In a quick test, with N = 1000, the looping code takes ~7 seconds and the matrix multiplication code ~0.5 seconds.

The resultant matrix may still be too large to open in your workspace, you could copy any individual rows or columns into a temporary and view those, or do a contour plot (heat-map) of the matrix to get a visual representation.